# Getting the "From" address from the textbox(Sending e-mails via C# application)

Tags: c#, winforms, email, visual-studio-2022, hotmail

So I wrote everything that's needed to send mail via Windows Forms. But I also want to get the "from" address from the text that is written to textbox by the user.Is there a way to do this? So far I couldn't find it.

Any help is appreciated,thanks in advance..

This is my code so far.

```
MailMessage msg= new MailMessage();
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@hotmail.com", "1234"); 

client.Port = 587; 

client.Host = "smtp.live.com"; 

client.EnableSsl = true;
msg.To.Add(textBox1.Text);

msg.From.Add(textBox4.Text); // The part where I got stuck
msg.Subject = textBox2.Text;
msg.Body = textBox3.Text;
client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from?view=net-8.0#examples) even have an example ...

Comment: You don't understand. I can easily set a value for "from" address. But I want user to also specify "from" address like the way s/he specifies the "to" , "subject"  and "body".

Comment: _" I can easily set a value for "from" address"_ - surely not as shown in above code? ( [`MailAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailaddress?view=net-8.0) does not have an `Add` method) _"But I want user to also specify "from" address"_ - so if you can do it with the others, what is stopping you here? What error do you get? What doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: It wasn't shown in above code cause I didn't need to write this "" msg.From=new MailAddress("xyz@hotmail.com"); "" for what I'm trying to do. When I write "msg.From.Add(textBox4.Text);" as shown in the code, I get an error starting with "CS1061:'MailAddress' doesn't contain a definition for 'Add'..."

Comment: Yes, of course. Because `MailAddress` _does not have an `Add` method_. Look into the example. `To` is a `MailAddress**Collection**`. `From` is a `MailAddress?`. So you need to set it (either in ctor arg or) `msg.From = new MailAddress(textBox4.Text);`

Comment: Okay it is fixed,thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because `MailAddress` does not have an `Add` method.

Look into the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.from?view=net-8.0#examples): `To` is a `MailAddressCollection`. `From` is a `MailAddress?`. So you need to set it (either in ctor arg or) `msg.From = new MailAddress(textBox4.Text);`